# Dummy Variable, Reference Group

Tags: categorical-encoding, variable

My job is to create a dummy variable so that those who voted for the Labour Party are compared to a single reference group that includes all other voters.

1 = Conservative, 2 = Labour, 3 = Liberal Democrat, 4 = SNP, 5 = Plaid Cymru, 6 = Green Party, 7 = UKIP, 8 = BNP, 9 = Other

In this situation, would the reference group include {1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

So, the dummy variable would be:

- {2} -- > 1 (is Labour)
- {1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} -- > 0 (is not Labour)

Have I taken the right approach here? I am slightly confused because the reference group in this situation is included in the dummy variable. Usually, the reference group is not included because it is already assumed in the model.

Answer (score 2):

That looks correct. You would then want to include your dummy variable in a regression with a constant. Alternatively, you could create 2 dummy variables:

- DLabor=1 if group=2, else DLabor=0
- DOther=1 if group not equal to 2, else DOther=0

and then include the 2 dummy variables (DLabor and DOther) in a regression without a constant.